# Is it possible to display numbers inside a square root symbol in HTML? (Javascript?)

Tags: javascript, html

The question is self explanatory. I need to display numbers inside a square root symbol in html. Is it even possible? If its not, what is the best alternative? (aside from designing hr elements in the shape of a square root)

Comment: [MathML <msqrt>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Element/msqrt) should be the way, if more browsers did support MathML natively...

Comment: @Kaiido thats really convenient but unfortunately only firefox and safari supports it for now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```html
<span style="white-space: nowrap">
&radic;<span style="text-decoration:overline;">&nbsp;X + 1&nbsp;</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Btw is there no standard way of doing it? Like native code or something?

Comment: As talked about in another comment, a future more "standard" way of writing math symbols and formulas is with [MathML](https://caniuse.com/mathml). Otherwise HTML has resort to some tricks until your target browsers support it.

Answer (score 2):

**First, if you are not against using an external library.**

Just go ahead and use mathjax js library

```html
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
  <script id="MathJax-script" async
          src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
  </script>

<p>
$$ \sqrt{22b^3-c} \over 3b $$
</p>
```

**For a native solution**

You could use combining character code `&#x305` of UTF-8. It will combine the overline with previous codeblock.

But be really careful with your font settings. Depending on font, they might display as individual overline, or continuous overline (or even as separate character).  (Check behavior below with "Run code snippet")

```html
<p>Stack-overflows font settings results in continuous overline for combining characters in textarea in (Chrome on OsX)</p>
<textarea>
&radic;2&#x305;2&#x305
</textarea>
<p>
Stack-overflows stylesheet results in separated overlines for combining characters in paragraph (Chrome on OsX)
</p>
<p>
&radic;2&#x305;2&#x305  <span style="font-family: Courier">
  (in Courier &radic;2&#x305;2&#x305 )
</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this html symbol (example with square root of 2).

```html
&#8730;2
```

Comment: The numbers are not inside the square root, so visually its not professional

Comment: Put a border-top 1px.

Answer (score 0):

Designed a dynamic way to do this, only requirement is the internal font is monospaced.

"--char" tells the CSS how many characters are contained in the square root to draw the top line the correct width. The overline is not generating in white, but will outside of the code snippet. "--color" tells the CSS what color the overline should be, while the SVG can easily be changed color via the HTML (probably could be made easier but haven't done so).

```css
.sqrt {
  align-items: baseline;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.sqrt span {
  margin-left: -1ch;
  position: relative;
}

.sqrt>span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--char);
  height: 0.1em;
  top: 0;
  left: 1ch;
  background-color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<samp class="sqrt" style="--char: 1ch; --color: white;">
        2
    <span>
        <svg style="width: 1ch;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-miterlimit="2" clip-rule="evenodd" viewBox="0 0 59 100">
            <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5.5" d="M13.7 62.1 1.4 69.5"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="7.8" d="M30.9 96.3 9.2 62.2"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="1.5" stroke-width="4.2" d="M35.9 98h-6.1l-1.4-2.3"/>
            <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="7.8" d="M55 0v2.6L32.2 99"/>
        </svg>
        <span>6</span>
    </span>
</samp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Native [MathML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML) could be way to go here, as As Kaiido suggested in the comment. Meanwhile MathML gained support in (rest of) major browsers in 2023, so `<math><msqrt>(whatever)</msqrt></math>` should work in most contemporary browsers:

```html
<math>
  <msqrt>
   <msup>
    <mi>x</mi>
    <mn>2</mn>
   </msup>
  </msqrt>
  <mo>=</mo>
  <mi>x</mi>
</math>
```